# pyspark json nested generate field name

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks

suppose i am having the following json

```
{
"filename": "orderDetails",
"datasets": [
{
"orderId": "ord1001",
"customerId": "cust5001",
"orderDate": "2021-12-24 00.00.00.000",
"shipmentDetails": {
"street": "M.G.Road",
"city": "Delhi",
"state": "New Delhi",
"postalCode": "110040",
"country": "India"
},
"orderDetails": [
{
"productId": "prd9001",
"quantity": 2,
"sequence": 1,
"totalPrice": {
"gross": 550,
"net": 500,
"tax": 50
}
},
{
"productId": "prd9002",
"quantity": 3,
"sequence": 2,
"totalPrice": {
"gross": 300,
"net": 240,
"tax": 60
}
}
]
}
```

I would like to read the json to spark dataframe with name

filename,filename_datasets,filename_datasets_orderID.........

filename_orderDetails_productID,filename_orderDetails_quatity ...

what's a good way to do that ? Can I first generate my custom field name from the json schema itself
??

Comment: Can you share expected output in detail? Having said that, I would like you to share full list of columns and its format you need?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no a straight forward easy way to do it.
The guidelines to what you requesting are as follow:

1. You have to create a struct with all of your relevant fields.
2. cast your datasets field with your relevant schema using the definition at point 1.
3. explode it using `explode` method from (`pyspark.sql.functions`)
4. explode again the relevant field `orderDetails`
5. Select the relevant requested columns using a regular select statement.
6. done.